# How to reduce Query execution time for Optimization?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

Hi this current Query is taking too long to execute, what changes should be made to reduce the execution time?

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT  date_trunc({{period}}, wb.timestamp),
        CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT(org.id)) AS float) / CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT(wb.anonymous_id)) AS float) AS "marketing-lead conversion rate"
FROM website_prod.pages wb
FULL JOIN core_prod.organizations_organization org ON CAST(wb.timestamp AS DATE) = CAST(org.created_at AS DATE)
WHERE   NOT org.is_internal 
        AND wb.timestamp > date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '1 year'
        AND org.created_at > date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '1 year'
GROUP BY 1
```

```
QUERY PLAN

Sort Key: ((org.created_at)::date)
Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 608kB
-> Seq Scan on organizations_organization org (cost=0.00..259.02 rows=5080 width=19) (actual time=0.017..6.266 rows=5316 loops=1)
Filter: ((NOT is_internal) AND (created_at > (date_trunc('month'::text, (('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp with time zone) - '1 year'::interval)))
Rows Removed by Filter: 1540
-> Materialize (cost=69882.44..71012.63 rows=226038 width=45) (actual time=541.950..849.952 rows=3917712 loops=1)
-> Sort (cost=69882.44..70447.54 rows=226038 width=45) (actual time=541.945..592.666 rows=232720 loops=1)
Sort Key: ((wb."timestamp")::date)
Sort Method: external merge Disk: 14104kB
-> Seq Scan on pages wb (cost=0.00..42826.15 rows=226038 width=45) (actual time=40.801..358.687 rows=232720 loops=1)
Filter: ("timestamp" > (date_trunc('month'::text, (('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp with time zone) - '1 year'::interval))
Rows Removed by Filter: 72766
Planning time: 0.214 ms
Execution time: 26614.737 ms
```

Comment: Apart from bad formatting, that doesn't seem to be a complete execution plan, just a bunch of sequential scans and a sort. Please provide the complete plan and preserve the leading spaces.

Comment: Are you aware that using `FULL JOIN` *(an `OUTER` join)*, with your current `WHERE` clause simply turns it back in to an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the code should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your join looks extremely suspect to me...

```
  website_prod.pages wb
FULL JOIN
  core_prod.organizations_organization org
    ON CAST(wb.timestamp AS DATE) = CAST(org.created_at AS DATE)
```

In this case, you're joining all the rows in `wb` to all the rows in `org`, provided that they're "for" the same date.

So, for example, if on a particular date (say, `2021-04-01`), there are 10 `wb` records and 10 `org` records, the join will give all 100 combinations.

- Is that REALLY what you want???

I would "expect" something more like...

```
  website_prod.pages wb
FULL JOIN
  core_prod.organizations_organization org
    ON  wb.some_key = org.some_key
    AND CAST(wb.timestamp AS DATE) = CAST(org.created_at AS DATE)
```

Also, to make the join effective, the plan shows that it's having to sort the data in to time order.

You haven't specifically shown what indexes exist, but for the current query you would benefit from indexes on the columns being joined...  `wb.timestamp` and `org.created_at`.  Though that would change if you changed the join predicate as described above.

Comment: Would 'some_key' in wb.some_key meant a column name in wb? Would it be wb.timestamp in this case?

Comment: `wb.some_key` would be a column in `wb`, yes.  It would NOT be the `timestamp` for the reasons I already highlighted.  If you're not sure how to join to tables correctly, provided us with the full table definitions for both tables, or refer to you documentation / support staff regarding these tables.

Comment: there isnt a "common" column between the tables and was thinking if cross join would be a possibility?

Comment: Then you may need to join to a third / intermediate table first.  But cross joining is very unlikely to be the right answer.  As I described, 10 rows cross join 10 rows gives 100 rows - that's surely NOT what you want???